# what creates the default ObjectID in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Quite new to MongoDB. Going through the documentation.

From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#id-field 
*If the document does not specify an _id field, then MongoDB will add the _id field and assign a unique ObjectId for the document before inserting. Most drivers create an ObjectId and insert the _id field, but the mongod will create and populate the _id if the driver or application does not.*

Here it says MongoDB will create the _id.

From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/?_ga=2.24854906.1181826191.1496665143-146886871.1493019056#save-a-new-document-without-specifying-an-id-field 
*During the insert, the shell will create the _id field with a unique ObjectId value, as verified by the inserted document.*

And here, it says Mongo shell.

Is it the mongo shell that creates the default ObjectID or mongod? Hope someone can clarify!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the client doesn't provide the `_id`, the MongoDB server will do it. The shell is just another type of client; it provides the `_id` for inserted documents, so the server doesn't need to. But other drivers/clients may not, so in those cases the server does.

Answer (score 0):

If the client didn't create Id for the document, mongo server will create the _id when it creates a new document.